# How to tell if a Vue component is active or not

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue component that is wrapped in a `<keep-alive>` tag to prevent re-rendering.

Within the component, I want to react to some change in global data by firing a method. But, I only want to fire the method if the component is currently active.

Right now, I'm doing something like this:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return { 
      globalVar: this.$store.state.var,
      isComponentActive: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    foo() { console.log('foo') };
  },
  watch: {
    globalVar() {
      if (this.isComponentActive) {
        this.foo();
      }
    },
  },
  activated() {
    this.isComponentActive = true;
  },
  deactivated() {
    this.isComponentActive = false;
  },
}
```

But I was hoping there was already a property of the component's instance that I could reference. Something like this:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return { globalVar: this.$store.state.var };
  },
  methods: {
    foo() { console.log('foo') };
  },
  watch: {
    globalVar() {
      if (this.$isComponentActive) {
        this.foo();
      }
    },
  },
}
```

I can't find anything like that in [the documentation for the `<keep-alive>` tag](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive). And, looking at the Vue instance, it doesn't appear to have a property for it. But, does anyone know of a way I could get the "activated" state of the Vue instance without having to maintain it myself through the hooks?

Comment: probably use `the directive=ref` is one solution. add `ref="test"` for your component with `<keep-alive>`, then check the active status by `this.$refs.test ? true : false`.

Comment: That wouldn't work, the `$refs` array for the component is maintained even if the component is deactivated. Unless you meant from the parent scope, which wouldn't help me because the method I need to prevent from firing is within the deactivated component, not in the parent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably you can use `_inactive` (based on [the source code at  vue/src/core/instance/lifecycle.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/instance/lifecycle.js)
) to check whether the component is activated or not.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div>{{item}}</div>',
  props: ['item'],
  activated: function(){
    console.log('activated', this._inactive, this.item)
  },
  deactivated: function(){
    console.log('deactivated', this._inactive, this.item)
  },
  mounted: function(){
    console.log('mounted', this._inactive, this.item)
  },
  destroyed: function () {
    console.log('destroyed', this._inactive, this.item)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      testArray: ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }
  },
  methods:{
    pushItem: function() {
      this.testArray.push('z')
    },
    popItem: function() {
      this.testArray.pop()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="pushItem()">Push Item</button>
  <button v-on:click="popItem()">Pop Item</button>
  <div v-for="(item, key) in testArray">
    <keep-alive>
      <child :key="key" :item="item"></child>
    </keep-alive>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, perfect must have missed that. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't missed that, it's not public api and could be changed at any time. I would like to have such property on instance without creating it manually...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/components/keep-alive.js) it doesn't look like any state is changed in the component instance. Rather, the element is simply added or removed from the cache. So no, I don't think there's any option other than the lifecycle hooks.

Answer (score 1):

With Vue 3 composition API, you can set a `inactive` flag property in component using `onDeactivated`

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#deactivated

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party but the question is still a good one. Usually you set the childs visibility from the parent via props. But there are scenarios when you want the child to know by itself if it's visible or not without involving the parent.

This suggestion is a bit of a hack but works for vue 2 + 3 both.
I use the updated hook and check there if the element has a width or not as boolean plus a watcher to react to the changes.

However - if you need the update triggered in grand children, you would to bind a variable via `:key='someVar'` on their parent and then change that value like `someVar++` when the visibility changes. Otherwise the update in grand children won't fire.

Thanks @Sphinx for the snippet I addapted for my purpose.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div id="childisch"><slot></slot></div>',
   data() {
    return {
      isActive: false
    }
  },
    watch: {
        isActive(val) {
          if (val) {
            console.log('I know I am visible')
          } else {
            console.log('I am hidden')
          }
        }
    },
  updated(){
    const el = document.querySelector('#childisch')
    this.isActive = el.offsetWidth > 0
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      showChild: false
    }
  },
  methods:{
    toggleItem() {
      this.showChild = !this.showChild
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="toggleItem()">Toggle Child Visibility</button>
  <div v-show="showChild">
      <child>CHILD COMPONENT</child>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Composition API, you can do this:

```
<script setup>
const vm = getCurrentInstance()

onDeactivated(() => {
    console.log(vm?.isDeactivated) // true
})

onActivated(() => {
    console.log(vm?.isDeactivated) // false
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but it's super simple using the Composition API and you don't need to touch `getCurrentInstance()` - which I believe is part of the private API, so not safe to use (I believe?).

```
<script setup>
import { onActivated, onDeactivated } from 'vue';

const isVisible = ref<boolean>(false);

onActivated(() => {
    isVisible.value = true;
})

onDeactivated(() => {
    isVisible.value = false;
})
</script>
```